# Using map_df from purrr on a factor column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to count the number of responses in multiple columns for rows which all belong to one of four factors in the column `Paper`. I can sum the terms for each factor individually using map_df from purr as so

```
times <- in_all_waves %>% 
          filter(Paper =='Times') %>%  
          ungroup()  %>%    #function refuses to work without this 
          select(-Paper) %>%
        map_df(table) %>%   # use map_df from the purrr package to "table" each column
        rownames_to_column("response") %>% #convert the rownames to a column named response
        mutate(resp = case_when(response == 1 ~ "Remain", #change the resulting numbers  to the correct responses 
                        response == 2 ~ "Leave", 
                        response ==3 ~ "Will Not Vote", 
                        response == 4 ~ "Don't Know")) %>%  
      select(resp, everything(), -response) #reorder the columns with resp at the front, removing response
```

But when I try to do this without selecting just one column as so:

```
different_papers <- in_all_waves %>%
                      map_df(table) %>%
                      rownames_to_column("response") %>% 
                        mutate(resp = case_when(response == 1 ~ "Remain", #change the resulting 1s to No in resp
                          response == 2 ~ "Leave", 
                          response ==3 ~ "Will Not Vote", 
                          response == 4 ~ "Don't Know")) %>%  
                           select(resp, everything(), -response) #reorder the columns with resp at the front, removing response
```

I get the error `Error: Argument 9 must be length 4, not 5` which is a reference to this last column of factors. Is there a way to keep all of the  rows in the same tibble, or do they have to be in seperate ones for each factor?

No other suggested questions seem quite to match my query I'm afraid.

This is the dataframe I'm using in an rds format!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwq913lw13kxyw9/inallwaves.rds?dl=0

Comment: Both the code do not give me any error.

Comment: Could I see what your finished `different_papers` dataframe looks like please ? The first snippet of code does work for me but not the second ..

Comment: You can check it here - https://ibb.co/gz0YWpF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found just adding the column back in worked best !

```
tally_reader_number <- function(input_dataframe,newspaper_name) {
  
  #function takes the input of in_all_waves, tallies the number of different eu ref responses using map_df for a given newspaper factor (defined above)
  # and returns a dataframe of responese for each wave with the newspaper factor as a column 
  returned_dataframe <- input_dataframe %>% 
    filter(Paper == newspaper_name) %>%  
    ungroup()  %>%    #function refuses to work without this 
    select(-Paper) %>%
    map_df(table) %>%   # use map_df from the purrr package to "table" each column
    rownames_to_column("response") %>% #convert the rownames to a column named response
    mutate(resp = case_when(response == 1 ~ "Remain", #change the resulting numbers  to the correct responses 
                            response == 2 ~ "Leave", 
                            response ==3 ~ "Will Not Vote", 
                            response == 4 ~ "Don't Know")) %>%  
    select(resp, everything(), -response) %>% #reorder the columns with resp at the front, removing response
    mutate(Paper = newspaper_name)
  returned_dataframe$Paper <- as.factor(returned_dataframe$Paper)
  returned_dataframe$resp <- as.factor(returned_dataframe$resp)
  
  
  returned_dataframe
  
}
```